# IE8 Conditional Style sheet affecting all IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Some of my CSS elements don't work in IE8. So I am using a conditional style sheet to set `display:none` for them; however, this affects everyone using IE browsers no matter the version. I'm using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>website title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="web description">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <!-- Stylesheets -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css"><![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is you want to target all the old IEs including IE8, so `lte IE 8` (lower/equal) would work. You can also merge that `lt IE 9` into the above one actually, like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

For debugging, you can try to add something like `body {10px solid red !important;}` into your `ie8.css` and to see if that applies to the correct browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`[if lte IE 8]` means that the stylesheet is added if version of IE is *less than 8*. You need the `[if IE 8]` conditional.

Comment: Hi suseika, im still having the same problem, that doesnt fix it.

Comment: @RMD2411 Does the stylesheet turn out to be used even on versions of IE greater than 8?

Comment: @RMD2411 Could you include your ie8.css in the question?

Comment: @RMD2411 Are your sure you didn't put your code with `display:none` into a wrong file so it is simply used for all browsers?